# PHP object to array without namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to cast objects to arrays.
The default casting solution has strange behavior;
it prepends object (class) namespaces to the property names!

My code:

```
$assoc = (array) $product;
print_r($assoc);
```

The output:

```
[App\Model\Productid] = 1
[App\Model\Productname] = Samsung Galaxy S3
[App\Model\Productprice] = 120
```

What I need:

```
[id] = 20568
[name] = Samsung Galaxy S3
[price] = 120
```

Comment: Will json work: `$data = json_decode(json_encode($product), true);` It is hard to know without a better description of the object. (Of course, that doesn't drop "product", which can be done with an str_replace on the json string)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getshortname.php

Comment: How do you get from `Productid` to `id`?

Comment: Vote down? why? please...

Comment: @Milad I didn't vote down, but you are asking us to convert an object to an array without telling us anything about the object. Do a print_r on the object and show us what it looks like. Then, we may be able to answer.

Comment: The problem is not object, is the namespace before array keys, that everyone knows PHP add it to that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$obj = new \ReflectionObject($product); 
print_R($obj->getName());  // get namespace and class name here
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a built in method `get_object_vars(object $object): array`. See [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

```
$data = get_object_vars($product);
```